# How to differentiate between translation did not exist or the translation is the same as source?

Tags: c++, qt, translation, qtranslator

I am using `QCoreApplication::translate()` to translate text.

I am trying to understand whether a string has a translation.

Qt documentation states:

> If none of the translation files contain a translation for `sourceText`
>   in context, this function returns a `QString` equivalent of `sourceText`.

The problem I am facing is that I am getting results similar to this:

```xml
<message>
    <source>Side</source>
    <translation>Side</translation>
</message>
```

Where source and translation are the same.

In many languages, the translation is indeed same as the source. But if `translate("Side")` returns `"Side"`, I can't tell whether the translation was exactly `"Side"` or whether the translation was empty.

How can I differentiate between the two cases?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way.

Comment: Why do you think you need to? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is pretty straightforward what OP is facing. If there was no translation, the Library returns the source text. And in many languages, the translation exists but it is exactly the same as source. How to know which case the source fell in?

Comment: @GillBates XY in the QT-sources

Comment: @GillBates Also I am still not sure how did you realize that LRiO understood the Q. I think it is a disadvantage with the library.

Comment: There might always be solutions I believe. For example an alternative function call which takes the output string as parameter and return true or false can be my solution if exists. If such alternative does not exists it is still good to know that there is no alternative

Comment: @FirstStep: I'm asking why you ever need to know which case the source fell in. What difference does it make?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it is because OP wants to know if `translate()` succeeded or failed, so he can report that ("_The translation of This is That_" **or** "_Sorry we don't have a translation for This_"). If he sent `Side` and received `Side`, what does that mean? Does it mean there exist a translation and it is `Side` or there is no translation and the library returned the source `Side` (what he sent)?

Comment: @FirstStep: Okay, great, that's a good reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to differentiate between the two cases through a `QTCoreApplication::translate` call.

However, `QTranslator::translate` returns a null `QString` when the key is not found (Qt 5). So one option would be to keep a container around with every `QTranslator` you've added through `installTranslator()` (since `QCoreApplication` doesn't have a way to get those back).  Then, loop through that container, calling `QTranslator::translate()` on each instance in the container.  When you get a non-empty result, you found a translation; if no translator succeeded, then you know the key doesn't exist in any `QTranslator` you have.

#### psuedo-code:

```
bool hasTranslation(const char* key)
{
  QString result;
  if(!translators.size())
    return false;

  for(const auto& translator : translators)
  {
    result = translator->translate("context", key);
    if(!result.isNull())
      break;
  }
  return !result.isNull();
}
```

Comment: The `if (translators.isEmpty())` test is unnecessary, as `result` is initially null, and the loop will execute 0 times in that case - or you could just replace the loop with `std::any_of(translators.begin(), translators.end(), [key](QTranslator *t){return !t->translate("context", key).isEmpty();});` (note: prefer `QString::isEmpty()` to `QString::isNull()`).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no way. The `translate` function works in the following way: it iterates over all the translators that are available for the application, and tries to translate the source text with each of them. If it succeeds, it immediately breaks out of the loop and returns the translated text. If the aforementioned loop has finished, but the translation has not been found, it returns the source text in a form of a QString:

```
QString QCoreApplication::translate(const char *context, const char *sourceText,
                                    const char *disambiguation, Encoding encoding, int n)
{
    QString result;

    if (!sourceText)
        return result;

    if (self && !self->d_func()->translators.isEmpty()) {
        QList<QTranslator*>::ConstIterator it;
        QTranslator *translationFile;
        for (it = self->d_func()->translators.constBegin(); it != self->d_func()->translators.constEnd(); ++it) {
            translationFile = *it;
            result = translationFile->translate(context, sourceText, disambiguation, n);
            if (!result.isEmpty())
                break;
        }
    }

    if (result.isEmpty()) {
#ifdef QT_NO_TEXTCODEC
        Q_UNUSED(encoding)
#else
        if (encoding == UnicodeUTF8)
            result = QString::fromUtf8(sourceText);
        else if (QTextCodec::codecForTr() != 0)
            result = QTextCodec::codecForTr()->toUnicode(sourceText);
        else
#endif
            result = QString::fromLatin1(sourceText);
    }

    replacePercentN(&result, n);
    return result;
}
```

If you really need to be able to know if the translation could be found, you would have to subclass `QTranslator` class and override it's `translate()` function (since the `translate()` in `QCoreApplication` is non-virtual).